# IWebBrowser2 OnBeforeNavigate Event - EventHandler

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, atl

I was reading about the `IWebBrowser2-interface` and the `BeforeNavigate-Event` and the `OnBeforeNavigate Handler`. I was wondering about the following description:

> This member function is called by the framework to cause an event to fire before a navigation occurs in the web browser.

The quote can be found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/2chzz53b.aspx

My understanding was the follwing: an event gets fired and causes a method to be executed, but in the upper description it is completely the other way round.

Can anybody please clarify the situation for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wording is awkward because the `CHtmlView` is simply a thin wrapper around a COM object. It works like this:

1. Internet Explorer COM object fires a event on the [`DWebBrowserEvents2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768283%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface
2. ATL's event sink responds to this call by calling any registered handler methods for the `CHtmlView::BeforeNavigate` event.